# 'origin/master' is not getting updtated after 'git push origin' (when script is used)

Tags: git

When doing "git push origin" with a Bash script (where user and password is provided) 'origin/master' is not updated and and doing `git status` will show

```
 "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/origin' by 2 commits.
```

Doing the same thing without the script(without user and password provided)`origin/origin` gets updated just fine.

I narrowed down the problem to the way I preform the push, for some reason providing the username and password with the url of the remote causes the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

#save current working directory
current_dir=${PWD} 


read -r -p 'git commit message: ' comment  # prompt user for commit message
git add .                                  # track all files
git commit -m "${comment}"                 # commit with message


#git push origin master
git push http://username:password@git.url master
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit!

Comment: Run "git branch -a" and tell me the output.

Comment: * master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/anaNAS
  remotes/origin/master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script doesn't do `git push origin` but rather `git push <url>`:

> ```
> #git push origin master
> git push http://username:password@git.url master
> ```

That is, you've given a URL, rather than the name `origin`.  So if the push succeeds, Git has no idea that it should update your own `origin/master`.

You can do any of these:

- use `git push origin master` (the commented out line)

  - perhaps also setting the `url` or `pushurl`, either permanently or temporarily
- follow up the `git push` to the URL-based name with a `git fetch origin`
- forcibly update your own `origin/master`

Remember that `origin/master` is a name that *your* Git sets, and updates, in order to remember what *their* Git—the one over at `origin`—last said was *its* `master`:

- When you run `git fetch origin`, your Git calls up their Git, asks their Git about *all* their branches, obtains any new commits and other items you need, and updates all of your `origin/*` names.
- When you run `git push origin master`, your Git calls up their Git, offers them any new commits you have that they don't (along with other items that go with that), and asks them to set *their* `master` to the last of the commits you just pushed.  They either say *OK, I did that* or *No, I refuse to do that <for whatever reason>*.  If they say they did that, your Git updates your `origin/master` because your Git knows what their Git just set their `master` to.

But in this case, your Git *didn't* phone up the Git at `origin`.  Instead, it called some random Git server over at `http://username:password@git.url`.  *That* Git may or may not have updated its `master`, but what relationship does that Git have with `origin`?  As far as your Git knows, none whatsoever.  So your Git *doesn't* update your `origin/master`.

To make your Git realize that these are the same "other Git", you must make sure that the `git push` calls up the other Git under the name `origin`.  If you can't make that work (but you can, see below), you can run `git fetch origin` to have your Git pick up the update, or use `git update-ref` (but don't do that).

#### How to supply a URL permanently, or for just one `push` operation

When you run:

```
git push origin master
```

Git first tries to get the URL for the `push` from the result of:

```
git config --get remote.origin.pushurl
```

If that doesn't find anything, it tries:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

(which also supplies the URL for `git fetch`).  This one *must* succeed; if it fails, you can neither `git fetch` nor `git push` at all using the name `origin`.

Now that your Git has the URL (from `git config --get`), your Git goes on to try to call up the other Git.  This can succeed or fail on its own, of course.

So, to *permanently* set the URL for *both* `git fetch` *and* `git push`, you can change the `remote.origin.url` setting.  To permanently set the URL for `git push` only—leaving the `git fetch` one alone—you can set or change the `remote.origin.pushurl` setting.  There are multiple different ways to do this; the one aimed at command-line users is the `git remote` command:

```
git remote set-url --push origin http://username:password@git.url
```

would for instance record the given user-name-and-password based URL into `.git/config` under the `remote.origin.pushurl` setting.  My own preference is to run `git config --edit` and simply edit the `.git/config` file in my editor, but you might prefer to use `git remote set-url`.  **Note that this will record your password in a file**, which is not secure; but you have already done this in the script anyway, so it's not actually much worse than before.

Alternatively, you can run:

```
git -c remote.origin.pushurl=http://username:password@git.url push origin master
```

in your script.  The `-c` option to `git` sets a single configuration item for the duration of that particular Git command.  So this will work without having to store the username-and-password in the Git configuration file (though as before, these continue to be stored in cleartext in your script).

Comment: Thank you very much, wish I could up-vote your answer but unfortunately don't have enough reputation. Makes perfect sense. I used one of your suggestions and now all works perfectly.